# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on setting Core Data entity property

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I've seen some problems with people using an integer type in the Core Data model, but then trying to use integers in code while not setting the checkbox to use scalars.  But, I'm actually doing that.

1. Create an Integer 64 property on an entity
2. Create an NSManagedObject subclass from that entity
3. Check the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" box.

This generates:

`@interface State : NSManagedObject
 @property (nonatomic) int64_t serverId;
 @end`

But, then, during runtime, I'll get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with this code:

`int64_t someValue = 313;
 State *state = ... // standard [NSEntityDescription insert code
 state.serverId = someValue;`

where 'state' is the NSManagedObject subclass, and serverId is the Integer 64 property.
But, the following code works:

`state.serverId = [NSNumber numberFromInt:someValue];`

But, since serverId is actually declared as int64_t, this results in a warning.  And, actually trying to access the value gives something that might be a pointer address (although %@ looks like what I expect).

So, I guess my question is, what in Core Data has gotten stuck on my int64_t's being NSNumber's?  Looking at the Model and NSAttributeDescription's, it's an NSInteger64AttributeType.

Things that I think may have something to do with this:

- Forgetting to check the box, and regenerating the class
- Updating the schema and migrating

In the first instance, this seems like a common case, and I've tried this, and, as expected, I can't reproduce my problem.  For the second case, I deleted my model file and recreated everything, deleted my DerivedData directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to  support both 32 ad 64 bit architectures you will want to stay away form scalars.

For a start read the [CocoaTouch 64 Bit Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

In your code pay attention to `int` and `NSInteger`

In the `model` use `Integer32` or `Integer64`. The bit size is depending on the app requirement for number space. If you serverID's are all around 313 you should be ok with 32 bits, if you have really big number go with integer64.

I understand you currently use integer64. To avoid the need for migration just stick with integer64 for now. But test your app for a 32-bit architecture, too.

In the entity class use NSNumber, don't use scalars for attributes stored in the storage.

```
@interface State : NSManagedObject
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *serverId; 
@end

@implementation State
   @dynamic serverId;  // this will create the default accessor for you
@end
```

CoreData will do the magic of converting from Integer32 or Integer64 to NSNumber and you will not need to worry about conversion warnings.

In you app code use `numberFromInteger` not `numberFromInt`

```
 state.serverId = [NSNumber numberFromInteger:someValue];
```

---

### Custom Accessors as Integer

If you have a lot of NSIntegers  and you want to write something like

```
 NSInteger someInteger;
 state.serverIdInteger =  someInteger;
 // or
 someInteger = state.serverIdInteger;
```

then you will need a custom accessor for the `serverID`. Your model does not change, the changes are to the entity class.

```
@interface State : NSManagedObject
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *serverId; 
   @property (nonatomic) NSInteger serverIdInteger; //custom accessor
@end

@implementation State
@dynamic serverId;  // this will create the default *serverId* accessor 

// now do custom accessor
-(void)setServerIdInteger:(NSInteger)anInteger {
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"serverId"];
   [self setServerId:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:anInteger]];
   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"serverId"];
}

-(NSInteger)serverIdInteger {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"serverId"];
    NSNumber *tmpValue = [self serverId];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"serverId"];
    return (tmpValue!=nil) ? [tmpValue integerValue] : 0;
}

@end
```

Comment: An int64_t is 64-bit on any platform.  That's the definition of a 64-bit int.